# zmi: duplicates in add products list

Tags: zope

I have an old-style product with several classes. In the class, I have defined the meta_type and I have also registered them in `__init__.py`, i.e.:

```
def initialize(context):
    context.registerClass(
        ClassA.ClassA,
        permission = "Add ClassA",
        constructors = (ClassA.manage_addClassA,
                        ClassA.manage_addClassA),
        icon = 'www/images/ClassA.gif'
    )
```

This worked fine until I updated my Zope from 2.9 to 2.13. Now in the zmi, in the "Add Products" dropdown list, these meta_types are shown two times each.

I tried to track the source of this error:

1. ObjectManager.py, filtered_meta_types
2. ObjectManager.py, all_meta_types
3. getattr(Products, 'meta_types', ())

Now I don't know where to look next :)

It's only a nuisance, it does not cause any problems in the functionality of the product. Maybe I should update it to a new-style zope product, but I'm curious where this error comes from.

Comment: Curious indeed; I have not seen that myself. Is there a `configure.zcml` file with a `five:registerPackage` directive perchance?

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, that did it: I only had to comment it out in the configure.zcml and the duplicates are gone. It didn't work the other way around: commenting it out in the `__init__.py` removed both duplicates. Maybe you want to post the solution so that the question is marked answered? :)

Comment: There you go; with expanded explanation as to *why* your initializer is called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your `<five:registerPackage />` registration from the `configure.zcml` file, because your legacy package is using the `Products.` namespace.

The `Products.` namespace has always been auto-loaded; the `initialize(context)` function is implicitly being loaded for that namespace since before it was an official namespace.

When Zope started to support packages *outside* of the `Products.` namespace, however, the decision was made (wisely) to make registration explicit instead, and the `<five:registerPackage />` was introduced to let you use the old registration hook if you still needed it.

In your case, however, that means your `initialize()` function is being called twice; once because it is a `Products.` package, and once because you explicitly registered it.